# Destroy & re-create Service in my case

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

In my activity, I start my service in `onStart()` of my activity & bind to service in `onResume()` :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

   private boolean isBound;

   ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection(){...};

   @Override
   public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
   }

   @Override
   public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

        Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        isBound = bindService(service, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); 
   }
}
```

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` class , in its `onReceive()` callback, I want to **re-start** my service. I mean **destroy** it completely & **creat** it by calling `startService()` again:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //I want to re-start MyService from scratch, i.e. destroy it & start it (create it) again
       Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
       stopService(service);
       startService(service);
   }    
}
```

But as Android document says, my above code doesn't guarantee the previous started service will be destroyed since I have also bind to it.

My question is what is the most efficient way to **unbind** `MyService` in `MyBroadcastReceiver` to restart `MyService` from scratch? As you see, the bound `myConnection` instance is in MyActivity...

Comment: What's your motivation for needing to restart the service from scratcg rather than just using the lifecycle methods to reset it's state?

Comment: I have some actions in onCreate() of MyService, and it has to be there. I want to trigger onCreate() of MyService when onReceive() is called in BroadcastReceiver. That's to have a clean service starting from scratch again at that point.

Comment: Your architecture sounds pretty hokey. If you have code in `onCreate()` of your `Service`, that you want to have executed when your receiver is triggered, move that code into a separate method and have your receiver call `startService()` with an extra in the passed `Intent` that tells your `Service` to reinitialize itself. In `onCreate()` and in `onStartCommand()` you can then call the "initialize" method.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) documentation:

> Multiple clients can connect to the service at once. However, the
>   system calls your service's onBind() method to retrieve the IBinder
>   only when the first client binds. The system then delivers the same
>   IBinder to any additional clients that bind, without calling onBind()
>   again.
>
> When the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys the
>   service (unless the service was also started by startService()).

So, when using your service, don't start your service using `startService(intent)`, but rather by called `bindService(service, conn, flags)`.  This way, if your `Activity` is the only activity bound to the service, when you call `unbindService(ServiceConnection conn)` the system will kill your service, then you can rebind afterwards.

Comment: But I need to start my service. I have functions in onStartCommand(), which needs to be performed.

Comment: Could the onBind() method not serve the same purpose?

Comment: @Leem.fin Please check this link for more info on bind and onStartCommand and how it is different? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/xxo_Tls7CDk